# Android Notification Icon

Tags: android

New to Android development.  I'm wondering if its possible to programmatically draw an icon to put in the notification bar? What if we want the icon to display some dynamic text for something like battery level?

If anyone has a code sample it would be nice.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I would think there should be a way to reference a class as a drawable resource so an image can be drawn programmatically, but I dont spend very much time with or know very much about Android... :(

Answer (score 4):

Call the function where we want notification.

```
 public void notification(String name) {

            final int id = 2;
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
            int icon = R.drawable.fbc;
            CharSequence tickerText = "facebook";
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification checkin_notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,
                    when);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence contentTitle = "You are name is"+ name;
            CharSequence contentText = "Do You want to Check-in ?? ";

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, LoginTab.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        notificationIntent, 0);
                checkin_notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle,
                        contentText, contentIntent);
                checkin_notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(id, checkin_notification);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Notification Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).

[Example here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Thats not what i'm looking for. Thanks though.  I know how to put up a notification.  I'm asking about using an image that was drawn on the fly for the notification icon.  Notification.icon only seems to accept an int for a resource ID.

Comment: The status bar icon cannot. But the extended text that appear after you expanded the notification is possible.

Comment: Ugh, that seems crappy. So to stick some text on top of an icon in the status bar you'd have to make a different icon for every scenario?

Comment: If you just want to show a count, you set the number property of the notification and it will overlay a badge with a number in it.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here  you wouldn't be able to have an icon larger than the standard size, not really big enough for anything readable

Answer (score 1):

have you had a look at LevelListDrawable?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html